# Support Vector Machine Illustration

Tags: svm

Does anyone can give an example of a SVM? Especially how to get the `w` and `b` from a training set?

I tried to search in the internet but it only gives me a large amount of abstract mathematics.

As I am not good at it, so could anyone give me an illustration of a SVM with an example in very details?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 8):

This diagram on wikipedia provides a good example of what the goal is, but in truth a support vector machine *is* a lot of complicated math. You find the values for `w` and `b` by optimizing a quadratic programming system, and when hidden behind vector mathematics, it's not entirely clear what's going on unless you're well-tuned to the math.

[image: diagram]